# How to display the selected value from the dropdown in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
thicknessexpanded: false,
method(){
    thicknessOnClick: function (event) {
      this.thicknessexpanded = !this.thicknessexpanded;
    },
    }
```

```css
.dropdown-check-list3 {
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-check-list3 .anchor3 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 255px;
  color: #70737a;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: #ffff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 140px 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.dropdown-check-list3 .anchor3:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 35%;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.dropdown-check-list3 .anchor3:active:after {
  right: 8px;
  top: 21%;
}
.dropdown-check-list3 ul.items3 {
  width: 254px;
  background-color: #ffff;
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
.dropdown-check-list3 ul.items3 li {
  background-color: #ffff;
  list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-check-list3.visible .anchor3 {
  background-color: #ffff;
}
.dropdown-check-list3.visible > span.anchor3:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
 <div
              class="dropdown-check-list3"
              :class="{ visible: thicknessexpanded }"
              tabindex="100"
            >
              <span class="anchor3" @click="thicknessOnClick">Select (mm)</span>
              <ul class="items3">
                <div class="checkbox-alignment-application-filter">
                  <li
                    id="thickness-filter1"
                    class="vh-product"
                  />
                  <label class="productlist-specific" for="thickness-filter1"
                    >2.0mm</label
                  >
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-alignment-application-filter">
                  <li
                    id="thickness-filter2"
                    class="vh-product"
                  />
                  <label class="productlist-specific" for="thickness-filter2"
                    >22.0mm</label
                  >
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-alignment-application-filter">
                  <li
                    id="thickness-filter3"
                    class="vh-product"
                  />
                  <label class="productlist-specific" for="thickness-filter3"
                    >3.0mm</label
                  >
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-alignment-application-filter">
                  <li
                    id="thickness-filter4"
                    class="vh-product"
                  />
                  <label class="productlist-specific" for="thickness-filter4"
                    >4.0mm</label
                  >
                </div>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

From the dropdown i want to select the particular value, And display(bind) the selected value in the dropdown.as so and so.

For that i have written functionality, So not sure how to bind the  selected value in the dropdown.

Can anyone please help me on it. Not sure what's wrong with the code. Or how can i start in order to display accordingly.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work.

Comment: @Terry because not sure how to start, struck at the logic

Comment: No, it outright doesn’t work. Syntax error and VueJS library not even included.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using vue.js, why not implementing a dropdown component, passing it the items to select andd using v-model directive to bind the selected item in your vue data, and also the dropdown ?

That's how it works in many dropdown components I've used in vue.

You can do like this :

### Form component

```
<template>
<CustomDropDown :items="itemsList" v-model="chosenSize" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
   data() {
      return {
         itemsList = ["2mm", ...],
         chosenSize = itemsList[0]
      }
   }
<script />
```

### Dropdown component

```
<template>
 ... dropdown code 
 <li @click="updateValue(item)" v-for="item, index in items" :key="index">item</li>
 ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
props: ["value", "items"],
data() {
  return {
    chosen: this.value
  }
},
methods: {
   updatedValue(item) {
      this.chosen = item;
      this.$emit("input", item);
   }
}
</script>
```

This way you can customize dropdown by knowing at all time which item is selected and have a v-model in the parent form component.

I advise you to have a look at this: [vue js components][1]

Hope it helps!
[1]: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: i am using @click and in vue i am toggling the dropdown,  Can u please provide some example for the same